# Can ADB see if the browser is fully loaded?

Tags: android, android-emulator, adb

I've created an app that interacts with the Android Emulator through ADB to send the browser to a particular URL, then screenshot the browser window.  I then grab the image and convert it server-side to a JPG.

Everything works great, however right now I am simply doing a thread.sleep() for 15 seconds to make sure the browser is finished loading the URL I pass in.  Well, this works fine for the most part, but some sites are done loading way before the 15 seconds, while others still need a few seconds.

I was wondering if there is a way through ADB that I can check if the browser is finished loading instead of setting a static time to wait?

Comment: Just to update, I was not able to find a reliable way through adb so I instead inspected 3 pixels in the screenshot to determine its RGB color.  If they match the color pattern of the loading bar, I wait a bit and take another screenshot until the bar is gone or until the timeout happens.  Not my favorite solution but I had a Friday deadline that I needed to meet!

Answer (score 1):

There is a way: just after opening the browser, load a javascript url that will output to console once the page is loaded. Then look for the output in logcat.
In android, all `console.log()` javascript calls are forwarded to logcat. (tag name depends on OS version, look for console, browser or WebCore)

exemple:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com ; sleep 1 ; adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "javascript:window.onload=function(){console.log('stackoverflow rocks hard.')}" -n com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity
```

You can then see the following line on logcat, when the website will be fully loaded:

```
11-16 23:03:53.887: D/WebCore(1672): Console: stackoverflow%20rocks%20hard. line: 1 source:
```

Comment: Thanks, I am 90% there using your suggestion.  I can pass in a unique ID with the javascript URL as you suggested so it can be logged... then I do a logcat to get the log and read to see if my ID is in there.  

My problem though is the javascript's onload is firing even before the window is loaded.  I am issuing the first load of the page, then in another process throwing the javascript URL to the browser (after 2 second delay), but it seems the javascript writes to console even before the page is loaded.  Do you have any idea why this may be happening?

Comment: I used the same code, but I am using C# and using Process.Start() to send the commands. I send the first command, which sets the URL then I send the second command 2 seconds later with the js.  And yes, the code is the same just instead of putting "stack overflow rocks hard" I put a unique key so I can then get the contents of the log through logcat to see if the ID is in there.  The problem is, the ID is in the log even while the page is still loading, thus my screenshot method executes prematurely.

Comment: I don't understand why it doesn't work for you. On my 2.3.4 android phone, I can clearly see it working. If I fire the second code after the page is loaded, no logs if i fire it before the loading completes, I can see the log line once loading is done. On the phone do you see a new window open or does the one shown by the first call is reused by the second call?

Comment: No, there is no new window that gets open, it re-uses the the same window.  I assume this is how it should be correct?  BTW, I am running 2.3.3 but I doubt this will be an issue.

Comment: Yes, same window must be used. 2.3.3 or 2.3.4 should not be an issue. maybe it is a difference in adb implementation? I am on a mac, adb version 1.0.29, SDK 15. what is your sdk version? can you try to replace window.onload by document.onload or document.body.onload ? can you post your code c# code where you do the adb calls?

Comment: is there a way to do this 
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d http://www.stackoverflow.com ; sleep 1 ; adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d "javascript:window.onload=function(){console.log('stackoverflow rocks hard.')}" -n com.android.browser/com.android.browser.BrowserActivity

with opera mini?